# Mysterious Magical Donuts

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> When hungry, I like to make friends. 
> After eating a donut, I become terribly violent. 
> After eating two, I might punch you, or I might befriend you. 
> Who am I, and what are these donuts made of?

Big hint: I'm surrounded by donuts right now.

Comment: If Snickers is the answer, i will feel sad :/

Answer (score 3):

my take is that you (and your friends) are

> Carbon (atoms)

When hungry, I like to make friends.

> In valency theory, carbon atoms form allotropes with other carbon atoms 
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropes_of_carbon

After eating a donut, I become terribly violent.

> (p.s.) This was the trigger for my guess, but I have always thought that hydrogen atoms look like a donut....
>  CH- is an instable structure, which is reactive and violent

After eating two, I might punch you, or I might befriend you.

> CH2- is even more unstable and is often said to *attack* other atoms.
>  https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Carbene
>  Alternatively, it can be stable when bonding with another C atom, forming C2H2  (Ethene)

Who am I, and what are these donuts made of?

> You are Carbon, and the Donuts are Hydrogen (Shells) made out of electron (and proton/quarks depending on how far you want to deepdive ....)

big hint: I'm surrounded by donuts right now.

> Hydrogen atoms exist freely in many substance, such as water/acid/etc .....

Now i am hungry after all these donut talks hahaha

Comment: You got the first part. However, your donuts don't seem to quite match up with the hint i gave. I'm looking for something more obvious that fits it.

Comment: Still can't get it on my head yet..... any further hints to drive this in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

To resurrect this old unsolved puzzle, the OP has confirmed in [a comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75640/mysterious-magical-donuts?rq=1#comment224695_75686) that @Kryesec was correct to say that you are...

> ...a **carbon atom**.

However, I believe the 'donuts' in question are actually...

> ...**oxygen atoms**, since the chemical symbol for oxygen is 'O', which is also the shape of a ring donut.

Line-by-line:

*When hungry, I like to make friends.*

> A carbon atom can make 4 [covalent bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond) with other atoms/ions. This can be imagined as a carbon atom 'hungry' to make connections with other atoms/ions, which - once bonded to it - could be considered its 'friends'. Carbon's ability to do this is a useful property that helps to make possible so many of the structures vital for life.

*After eating a donut, I become terribly violent.*

> When carbon bonds with an oxygen atom (symbol 'O', also the shape of a ring donut, recall) it forms **[carbon monoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_monoxide)** (CO), a poisonous, flammable gas most often created by incomplete combustion and potentially lethal to creatures that require oxygen to live (like us!) as it will bind to haemoglobin in the bloodstream, instead of oxygen doing so, eventually starving the body of the vital oxygen it needs to live and killing it (a *terribly violent* action indeed).

*After eating two, I might punch you, or I might befriend you.*

> When carbon bonds with two oxygen atoms at once, [**carbon dioxide**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide) is formed, a chemical which might cause asphyxiation to humans and other animals if breathed in place of oxygen in large enough quantities (an act that could be considered harmful like a *punch*) but which is also vital for the process of [photosynthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthesis) in plants, thereby being a *friend* to us by helping to keep all life in balance.

*Who am I, and what are these donuts made of?*

> As established, you are **carbon**, the donuts are **oxygen**.

*Big hint: I'm surrounded by donuts right now.*

> There are oxygen molecules in the air all around us!

Answer (score 0):

Are you?

> A hungry health coach?

*When hungry, I like to make friends.*

> As long as your new friends have food, who wouldn't?

*After eating a donut, I become terribly violent.*

> You're angry that someone brought you unhealthy food to satisfy your hunger.

*After eating two, I might punch you, or I might befriend you.*

> After eating two donuts you might become really angry and punch your new friend or you may have accepted that a healthy life choice is not worth missing out on donuts.